# How can I get default value using @ModelAttribute in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I am practicing ModelAttribute in Spring MVC I had read that if no value is supplied then it will load default value so is there any way we can achieve that. I have tried below program and when I comment the setName() method line then no value is displayed. Could anyone help me out how we can achieve that if it is possible?

User.java

```
public class User{
    private String name; //generate getter and setter
}
```

UserController.java

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value="init", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String saveCountry(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, ModelMap model) {
        user.setName("ABC");
        model.addAttribute("userName",user.getName());
        return "output";
    }   
}
```

output.jsp

```
<h3>Name: ${userName}</h3>
```

Comment: You've misunderstood if you were expecting `name` to get a "default" value from somewhere. The duplicate explains things pretty well (the second answer).

Comment: I am not getting that

Comment: Well, it doesn't really matter since it doesn't do what you thought it does. The answer to your question "How can I..." would be "you can't".